# ASP.net Entity Framework DropDownList Source Query not Returning Any Result

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, html-select

When I try the following SQL query, I get the result, I want:

```
SELECT City FROM Hotel GROUP BY City
```

But the following Entity Framework query does not returning any result:

```
string CityKey = CityDropDownList.SelectedValue;
MedicalEntities entity = new MedicalEntities();

CityDropDownList.DataSource = (from p in entity.Hotels
                               where p.City == CityKey
                               group p by p.City into g
                               select new
                               {
                                  City = g.Key
                               }).ToList();
```

I have tried so many variations of that query but no go.
I guess, its pretty straight forward and no extra information is needed. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you just trying to get a list of cities that hotels are in?

Comment: I am trying to get the cities in the Hotels table but there are too many duplication cities in Hotel tables. I mean there are maybe 20 hotel in the same city but in order to ignore those duplications I have used group by clause. If I delete this group by, it works but in the dropdownlist there are 20 Düsseldorf city, 10 Köln etc. I want to get rid of those repetitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you think you need to use the Group by..

```
CityDropDownList.DataSource = entity.Hotels.Select(x => new { City = x.City })
    .Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: I fall in love with "Distinct" = ) it works thanks, I will accept it as correct in 3 minutes